# Laminate layout - Sanity check

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor, laminate

I decided to be brave and try to lay laminate myself for the first time, since it's just one small room [14m2]. I measured all my walls and used Adobe Illustrator to create an outline of it, offset each edge inwards by 1cm for the expansion gap, and created a mock-up of how the planks should be laid out - see the image below. On this image:

- Dark gray planks are full-length
- Light gray ones are full-length but have chunks taken out of them
- Same-coloured planks are two parts of the same cut board

  - The pink ones are 1/2 of a board
  - The blue ones are 2/3 and 1/3
- The two black dots on the top left are radiator pipes

I plan to cut the boards in the top and bottom rows so they are roughly even widths [the room was 13 boards and 4cm tall, which would have ended up very uneven if I started with full-width boards on one end].

The reason I don't just continue the second row with the other half of the pink plank is because the room is exactly 3.5 boards wide - so I'd end up repeating every second row and create a non-staggered shape; so I opted to shuffle in some 1/3 and 2/3 lengths in there too; while trying to avoid a 'staircase' pattern.

I was intending on starting in the bottom-right corner and working from there so I can more easily slot the plank under the door frame (that door connects to the hallway, which already has laminate in it).

Does this plan look/sound sane? Do you have any advice for how I can ensure that the two light gray pieces in the top centre could be most easily slotted together; or how to most easily lay down the last row in the top left with the radiator pipes? Anything else I should look out for?

Thank!

[image: Laminate layout]

Comment: It looks good to me. I assume you will cut each as you install it.

Comment: Yep, I'll measure and cut as I go along; that way I hope to catch any slight unevennesses in the wall. But the flat is a new build so hopefully shouldn't be too wobbly.

Comment: I hope you are correct on the straight wall but you will be ok. Thanks for letting us know the status.

Comment: The easiest way to handle the pipes is to figure out how much to rip the first piece so that the seam ends up right up the centerline of the pipes.  Then you just notch the boards and wiggle them in.  However, this might throw everything else off.